# SD card permissions are not getting changed

Tags: android-sdcard, android-permissions, android-external-storage

I changed SD card permissions in init.rc as:

```
mkdir /storage/sdcard1 0700 system system
```

but it's not getting reflected when I mount the SD card onto the device. It's still showing as 0771.
How can I change default permissions of my external SD card?

Test cases in the below CTS package deals with external storage:
**com.android.cts.appsecurity.AppSecurityTests**
Since some of the test cases were failing, I made the above change.. But it's still not working.. Please help!

Comment: How did you modify init.rc? If you just remounted rootfs as writable and edited it then it will be overwritten when you reboot and I don't think those changes will actually take effect on a running system.

Comment: No, I changed init.hardware.rc file in the code and then gave a build. So the same file will be copied to DUT. Hence, I don't think it'll be overwritten on reboot. Instead it can be overwritten from somewhere else in the android code, but I absolutely have no idea from where?

Comment: I extracted init.hardware.rc from the device and checked, the permissions are same as in the build: "mkdir /storage/sdcard1 0700 system system" but when I check from the command prompt it displays: "drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_r          1970-01-01 05:30 sdcard1" which is "0771" :(

Comment: Okay - I believe it is a problem with custom roms. See, eg https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62141 where various storage folders aren't writeable. The permissions seem to be applied by the /system/core/sdcard component using a FUSE file system. See https://possiblemobile.com/2014/03/android-external-storage/ for more details. Short version: apps still need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on custom roms for some reason.